# Sails JS - Add a document and return the entire collection in the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, sails.js

How can I add a new document and return the whole collection? For example, I want to add a message and the respose should have all messages added

```
create: function(req, res) {
        var user_id = req.token.sid;
        req.allParams().user = user_id;

        Message.create(req.allParams(), function(err, message) {
            if (err) return res.json(err.status, {err: err});

        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom route for your action in `config/routes.js`:

`'POST message/create' : { controller: 'MessageController', action: 'create' }`

And add some lines to your code in the `MessageController.js`:

```
create: function(req, res) {
    var user_id = req.token.sid;
    req.allParams().user = user_id;

    Message.create(req.allParams(), function(err, message) {
        if (err) return res.json(err.status, {err: err});

        Message.find().exec(function(err, messages){
            if (err) return res.json(err.status, {err: err});
            return res.json(messages);
        })
    });
 }
```

it works for me.

Comment: great, that's what I was doing but I thought there might be a better option but I see I was mystaken, thanks!